# Problem dual booting alongside Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 16 from DVD, but still only get Windows 10 log in.  I chose the option 'install alongside Windows 10', and let it automatically size disk.

How do I see Ubuntu at log in?

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

The above cmd outputs:

```
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/loop0: 1.4 GiB, 1459982336 bytes, 2851528 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 21CEDCE4-4D19-414B-B17E-ABAD653E02D1

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2050048    2582527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     2582528    3606527    1024000   500M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda4     3606528    3868671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     3868672 1037878334 1034009663 493.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1902323712 1953523711   51200000  24.4G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1037879296 1886214143  848334848 404.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  1886214144 1902323711   16109568   7.7G Linux swap
```

Partition table entries are not in disk order.

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*
Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 21CEDCE4-4D19-414B-B17E-ABAD653E02D1

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048    2050047    2048000  1000M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda2     2050048    2582527     532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda3     2582528    3606527    1024000   500M Lenovo boot partition
/dev/sda4     3606528    3868671     262144   128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda5     3868672 1037878334 1034009663 493.1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1902323712 1953523711   51200000  24.4G Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda7  1037879296 1886214143  848334848 404.5G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda8  1886214144 1902323711   16109568   7.7G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sda1: 1000 MiB, 1048576000 bytes, 2048000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sda1p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/sda1p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sda1p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sda2: 260 MiB, 272629760 bytes, 532480 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x500a0dff

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda2p1      1948285285 3650263507 1701978223 811.6G 6e unknown
/dev/sda2p2               0          0          0     0B 74 unknown
/dev/sda2p4        28049408   28049848        441 220.5K  0 Empty

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sda3: 500 MiB, 524288000 bytes, 1024000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x500a0dff

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda3p1      1948285285 3650263507 1701978223 811.6G 6e unknown
/dev/sda3p2               0          0          0     0B 74 unknown
/dev/sda3p4        28049408   28049848        441 220.5K  0 Empty

Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sda4: 128 MiB, 134217728 bytes, 262144 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sda5: 493.1 GiB, 529412947456 bytes, 1034009663 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda5p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sda5p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/sda5p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sda5p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sda6: 24.4 GiB, 26214400000 bytes, 51200000 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x73736572

Device      Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda6p1      1920221984 3736432267 1816210284   866G 72 unknown
/dev/sda6p2      1936028192 3889681299 1953653108 931.6G 6c unknown
/dev/sda6p3               0          0          0     0B  0 Empty
/dev/sda6p4        27722122   27722568        447 223.5K  0 Empty

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk /dev/sda7: 404.5 GiB, 434347442176 bytes, 848334848 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk /dev/sda8: 7.7 GiB, 8248098816 bytes, 16109568 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

Comment: Is Windows 10 UEFI or BIOS boot? And then did you install Ubuntu in same boot mode? What brand/model system?  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI and: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi Best to see details: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you may have inadvertently installed grub on the wrong drive... possibly a partition or a USB stick.

Make sure Grub is installed on the specific boot drive (most likely `/dev/sda`).  You can do this by reinstalling grub with these steps:

Boot to your live media (your live ubuntu install disk or usb stick).  Run the `Try Ubuntu` option.  Then go to a terminal shell and run these commands:

**Step 1:**

```bash
$ sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt # Make "X" the partition that has Ubuntu installed (i.e. /dev/sda2)
```

**Step 2:**

```bash
$ for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
```

**Step 3:**

```bash
$ sudo chroot /mnt
```

**Step 4:**

```
# update-grub
```

**Step 5:**

```
# grub-install /dev/sdX # (x is the hard drive that has linux installed (i.e. /dev/sda)
    update-grub
```

Now reboot the system.

---

Using the command `$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*` on my system shows:

```
Device     Boot     Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  102402047  102400000 48.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda2  *    102402048  204802047  102400000 48.8G 83 Linux
/dev/sda3       204802048  245762047   40960000 19.5G 82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4       245762048 3907028991 3661266944  1.7T 83 Linux
```

In this example Linux is installed on `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.

---

**Final Resolution**

The issue was resolve via chat with ensuring the install was performed in UEFI mode and choosing `Ubuntu` in the Bios boot option.

Ubuntu presents both the Windows and Ubuntu menu option in the Grub menu.  If the Bio Boot option (order) is set to `Windows` the system will boot directly to Windows.  Windows doesn't recognize other install OSes.

Comment: Win 10 is UEFI. I downloaded 16.4 and burnt to DVD drive and installed from that. I installed alongside Win 10 and let it split the 1 T disk in half. The machine is a Lenovo all in one B50-35, AMD A10,* GB RAM, 1TB,R7,A260,2GB graphics. The disk is split but only Win 10 boots as usual. I will wait for any further comments before trying what is suggested.

Comment: @EddieG Are you saying you started over and are having the same problem?  My answer was a solution to the original problem of your question... that you had installed Ubuntu but can't see it in the boot menu.  The steps I provided should resolved the issue of ` not seeing Ubuntu in the boot menu`.

Comment: Trying your instructions having loaded from DVD but cannot get past first instruction in Terminal. It says can't find /dev/sdaX/mnt in/etc/fstab

Comment: You will have to verify your partition where you installed Linux.  You can do this by typing this command:  `$ sudo fdisk -l`  (Don't include the dollar sign (`$`) in the command, it's representing the prompt where you type the command).  If you can't tell where you installed Ubuntu from the output, paste the content of the output to your question and we can tell you which partition will have your Linux installation.  It'll most likely be a number between 1 and 5.  You will place the `X` in step one with that number.

Comment: how do i copy and paste from terminal

Comment: @EddieG Try a snap shot with your phone.

Comment: don't know how to get the snapshot on webpage. What am I looking for in the terminal response?

Comment: I don't see any numbers in the output. It starts with invalid option 1

Comment: @EddieG I need to know the output of the command I gave you... what do you get when you type in the command: `sudo fdisk -l` from the live session?  You typed the error you get when you type the first line.  I need to know what you see after you type in the command so that you will know what to put in the first line.  If you take a picture of what you see on the screen, you can edit your question and click on the `image` icon where you're typing your question and drag and drop the image there.

Comment: Picture 3.3 MB and too big. Cannot get it to drop after dragging

Comment: I tried CTRL + C but it will not copy

Comment: It refers to usage then options then format then available columns

Comment: I'll have to leave it there and come back to it another time

Comment: @EddieG Post and update when it's convenient.  For your information I added the output of the command to my answer.  You should see something similar to my output.  In the example Ubuntu is installed twice on `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sda2`.  So I would replace the `X` in the first step with either `1` or `2` to perform the fix if my machine didn't have Ubuntu listed in the menu.

Comment: see info in amended question

Comment: L D James please see response from terminal pasted in edited question

Comment: It may take me up to an hour to get at a computer.

Comment: When you typed the steps did you get any errors?

Comment: I typed sudo fdisk -1and what you see is what appeared. Just to check I am doing this from the DVD trying Ubuntu although I have previously fully installed from this DVD. This time I used a terminal which allowed me to copy and paste.By working off the DVD will the terminal tell me where Ubuntu is installed?

Comment: @EddieG You typed the command in wrong.  That should be a lower case letter `-l` not the minus one `-1` you typed.  Can you try adding the output of this `lowercase -l` to your question?  `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*`

Comment: Herewith in edited question

Comment: I will add response to sudo fdisk -l /dev/sd*

Comment: It's sufficient what you just added.  It just shows a little more lines than necessary.  Ubuntu recently added the ram devices to the fdisk list.  The `/dev/sd*` would have filter for  a cleaner ouput.

Comment: By the way, I edited your message to make the commandline output easier to read.  The formatting was done by selecting the text you pasted and clicking on the `{}` code markup tag.

Comment: @EddieG Your output above shows `/dev/sda7` as your linux partition.  Try the steps in the answer again.  This time use `sda7` for the `sdaX`.  Replace the `X` with the number `7`.

Comment: Do I have to enter every character shown in each line of the answer?The first line of 1 and second line of 5 have letters at the right not visible

Comment: I think it might be (ie dev/sda)

Comment: @EddieG You can slide right and left to read characters.  The characters after the `#` sign are comments and are not part of the command.

Comment: It has generated grub configuration file and finished with root@ubuntu:/#.

Comment: Do I come out and reboot PC now?

Comment: @EddieG Did you get any errors?  Did you perform step #5?  If so, that should resolve the issue.  Let us know if you still don't see both OS in the boot menu.

Comment: I didn't run 5. it said sda 7 is already mounted. Shall I run 5?

Comment: The terminal has root@ubuntu as prompt not ubuntu@ubuntu

Comment: Can you specify what you typed in when you tried to run `Step 5`?

Comment: I didn't think I needed to run step 5

Comment: Shall I post response in question?

Comment: No.  Just type in the comment what you typed in when you ran step 5.  If you get errors before running step 5, can you tell us which step gave you errors?

Comment: I have not run step 5 and I don't think I saw any errors

Comment: I thought you had commented above that you got errors.  Look at the steps provided.  Step 5 is part of the fix.  I updated the answer to make the steps easier to read.

Comment: I will now run step 5

Comment: OK. Problem. Response to step 5 is:

Comment: sudo: unable to resolve host ubuntu (more to come)

Comment: Installing for x86-64-efi platform (more)

Comment: grub - install: eroor: cannot find efi directory

Comment: previously it said found windows boot manager on /dev/sda2@/efi/microsoft/boot/bootmgfw.efi done

Comment: I used 7 in sda step 5

Comment: @EddieG Notice the `Step 5` wording.  There shouldn't be a number in the command in that step.  The number represents a partition.  The step 5 is to install grub on the drive itself.

Comment: To be clear. Step 5 has sdX in it. Shall I leave it as X?

Comment: No.  I'm hoping the answer has clear text.  This way others can benefit with the steps.  Notice the answer is says replace the `X`.  The `X` is an unknown which will be replaced by the drive the user is working with.  In this case you are working with drive `a`.

Comment: So do I input grub-install /dev/sda?

Comment: Tried but no go

Comment: still says cannot find efi directory

Comment: EFI system is on sda2?

Comment: @EddieG Give me a second to format the resolution to the error you get with the grub install on /dev/sda.

Comment: @EddieG I have to run an errand.  I should be back with the hour.  I'll update my answer with the formatted steps.  A quick overview of what needs to be done can be found here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

Comment: Appreciate your help. After tomorrow I will not be able to respond for 12 days

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44883/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-problem-dual-booting-alongside-windows-10).

Comment: @EddieG Click on the chat link above.

Comment: @L.D.James I'm back

Comment: @EddieG Use the link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting for comments.  Extended chat-like dialog between two people are discouraged in the comment section.

Comment: @EddieG Sorry about the previous link.  This is the link I meant to give: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44883/discussion-on-answer-by-l-d-james-problem-dual-booting-alongside-windows-10 for the update information.